# Why is this JQuery animation jumpy?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I am trying to animate an image slowly, but it's just jumping suddenly after the delay, not actually sliding over. Any idea why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Picture').fadeIn(1000).delay(1500).animate({'top': '25px', 'left': '20px', 'height': '101px'},2000);
});
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that any JavaScript animation is not performance-optimized. Based on your description I can't tell if it's what @unclenorton is solving (sorting out a sequence for animation) or just plain' ol' jumpy "Well, not much we can do about this" animation.

Comment: what browser(s) are you testing in? Is it jumpy in all of them or just some of them (IE?)

Comment: I've tested in both Chrome and Safari, it has not been smooth on either.

Answer (score 1):

Try using callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Picture').fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $(this).delay(500).animate({'top': '25px', 'left': '20px', 'height': '101px'},2000);
    });
});
```

The anonymous function will be executed after `fadeIn` is complete.

**UPD**: No `sleep` function, changed to `delay`. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CbgzG/

**UPD2**: OP's code works just as well: http://jsfiddle.net/CbgzG/1/

Comment: @Matt, can you post a fiddle or give a link to the page in question?